# systemd-nspawn: DHCP Discover cannot pass through a bridge from a container

Tags: bridge, systemd-nspawn

**What I have:**

A Gentoo host and an Ubuntu container.

**What I want:**

To connect the container to the network and to the host.

**What I'm doing:**

I've created a bridge on the host and added my NIC to it. The IP address of the NIC has moved to the bridge and I can use internet as normal. Then I start my container with `systemd-nspawn --network-bridge=my-bridge ...`.

**What I get:**

On the container side I see `host0` interface which is configuring according to networkctl:

```
root@scratch:~# networkctl 
IDX LINK             TYPE               OPERATIONAL SETUP     
  1 lo               loopback           carrier     unmanaged 
  2 sit0             sit                off         unmanaged 
  3 host0            ether              degraded    configuring
```

If I sniff the traffic of the three interfaces (the bridge, the NIC, and vb-container) via Wireshard I see that DHCP DISCOVER goes through the bridge and vb-container but never though the NIC and ACK is never received.

**What I'm asking**

What am I missing? How do I get an IP address assigned to my container?

Answer (score 0):

If your image/dir uses systemd-networkd, this should work out of the box.  If it doesn't, you may need to fidget with network internals or try the default config (none of -n, --network-bridge, etc) which just gives your container the host networking.  You may need to update resolv.conf or DNS as the image can potentially override host.

In my case, I'm playing with RHEL CentOS, Fedora, etc. These distros use NetworkManager out of the box so it's easiest just to not specify network on the systemd-nspawn.

Note also you may need to boot into a target that enables networking.  systemd-nspawn on its own will just use the default target.

```
systemd-nspawn -b [opts] systemd multi-user.target
```

This example boots by running systemd with the provided target.  If I use single.target or default (graphical.target) I may have mixed results.